# Enter a valid date error received in django form

Tags: javascript, python, django, forms

I've seen a lot of questions like this one but not specifically for generic class views. I get the error "Enter a valid date" but only when I set the date to be 24/02/1992 for example because it is taking month/day/year. If I set it to 02/02/1992, it works. I need it to accept day/month/year.

I have a CreateView like this:

```
class ContractGenerateView(CreateView):
    model = Prestamo
    form_class = PrestamoFormCreate
    template_name = 'usuarios/generateContract.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(ContractGenerateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        data['form'].fields['fecha_primera_cuota'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'datepicker_primera_cuota'}
        data['form'].fields['fecha_primera_cuota'].widget.format = '%d/%m/%Y'
        data['form'].fields['fecha_primera_cuota'].input_formats = ['%d/%m/%Y']
```

with a simple form

```
class PrestamoFormCreate(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Prestamo
        fields = (
        'moneda', 'partner', 'fecha_primera_cuota', 'frecuencia', 'plazo_mensual', 'fecha_desembolso',
     'cupo', 'porcentaje_cuota_inicial', 'interest_rate', 'interes_moratorio', 'fee_abaco', 'cuota', 'fecha_final_contrato',
              'metodo_pago')
```

and a simple javascript in my template:

```
$(function () {
    $(".datepicker_primera_cuota").datetimepicker({
        timepicker:false,
        format: 'd/m/Y',
    });
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of pass [`input_formats`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.DateField.input_formats) into `get_context_data` you should set in on form's field:

```
 class PrestamoFormCreate(forms.ModelForm):
    fecha_primera_cuota = forms.DateTimeField(label="Date", input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y'])
    class Meta:
        model = Prestamo
        fields = (
        'moneda', 'partner', 'fecha_primera_cuota', 'frecuencia', 'plazo_mensual', 'fecha_desembolso',
     'cupo', 'porcentaje_cuota_inicial', 'interest_rate', 'interes_moratorio', 'fee_abaco', 'cuota', 'fecha_final_contrato',
              'metodo_pago')
```